# Adjective order (where to put the adjective )

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, meaning-in-context, adjectives, phrase-meaning

What should I say to describe the following context :

1- an intense 13-week course.

2- a 13-week intense course.

Answer (score 1):

According to the scheme of attribution of order ([ref.](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adjectives/order-of-adjectives/)), if we reckon that "13-week" represents a  *size* and "intense" a  *quality* the noun phrase must be written "**an intense 13-week course**".

Comment: A 13-week intense course sounds better to me which I find worded apparently in the order of importance.

Comment: @RamPillai I must say that my impression  before I checked the rule was that the more natural order was the inverse of what you find more logical and perhaps more pleasant, and thus the rule  seems to corroborate the possible fact that this is the usual order of these sorts of adjectives when I find them. For instance I find "a two weeks training course" to have adj. in the narural order and that is confirmed by the rule again as purpose comes after size. Why should the size be more important?  I think that both elements of information are important, but not comparable in importance.

Comment: It is matter of how one prioritizes it. Even mine might have been influenced that way :)

Comment: @ LPH  Thanks , I totally agree with you.